# How to access a few elements of a sparse matrix from R Matrix library?

Tags: r, sparse-matrix

Let's say I have a big sparse matrix:

```
library(Matrix)
nrow <- 223045
ncol <- 9698
big <- Matrix(0, nrow, ncol, sparse = TRUE)
big[1, 1] <- 1
```

Now I want to access the first element:

```
big[1]
Error in asMethod(object) : 
  Cholmod error 'problem too large' at file ../Core/cholmod_dense.c, line 105
```

For some reason it tries to convert my matrix to a dense matrix. In fact, looks like the method is inherited from Matrix rather than from a sparse class:

```
showMethods("[")
[...]
x="dgCMatrix", i="numeric", j="missing", drop="missing"
    (inherited from: x="Matrix", i="index", j="missing", drop="missing")
[...]
```

Of course I could use the full `[i, j]` indexing

```
big[1, 1]
```

but I want to access a few random elements throughout the matrix, like

```
random.idx <- c(1880445160,  660026771, 1425388501,  400708750, 2026594194, 1911948714)
big[ random.idx ]
```

and those can't be accessed with the `[i, j]` notation (or you'd need to go element-wise, not really efficient).

How can I access random elements of this matrix without converting it to a dense matrix? Alternative solutions (other packages, et) are welcome.

Comment: This error no longer gets raised. Not sure when the "[" method for dgCMatrix objects was changed but you now get 1 returned from big[1].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the elements of the Matrix directly using the S4 extraction `@` without converting it to an ordinary matrix first. For example,

```
big@x[1]
big@x[random.idx]
```

In fact, you can extract other attributes as well. See `str(big)`.

Comment: Please add some context to your answer, or an explanation which surely will result in a better quality answer

Comment: Doesn't quite work, if I say `big[2,2] <- 2` on a "normal" matrix I could access it as `big[9700]` but `big@x[9700]` doesn't work here. But basically your point is that one would have to look at the object's internal structure, which is fair enough.

Answer (score 2):

@qoheleth's solution works for me. Just add more context about how to access elements of sparse matrix randomly.

N.B.: for sparse matrix created using Matrix package, big_sparse_mat@x attribute stores the indices of all non-zero elements for the matrix. So the randomly access indices should be within the right range, otherwise, you will get NA values.

Assume one wants to extract elements that are larger than 2 from the sparse matrix, the following code will do:

```
select_inds <- which( big_sparse_mat@x > 2.0)
select_elements <- big_sparse_mat@x[select_inds]

min_val <- min(select_elements)
max_val <- max(select_elements)
```